# Tapkee PCA and OpenCV PCA gives different results

Tags: opencv

Can anyone explain which part is different between the two?

Tapkee:

```
TapkeeOutput output = initialize()
    .withParameters((method=tapkee::PCA,
                     target_dimension=3))
    .embedUsing(imageE);
```

OpenCV:

```
cv::PCA pca(image.reshape(1,image.rows*image.cols), Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL, 3);
```

Comment: tapkee kernelPCA yields similar result to PCA in opencv, instead of tapkee PCA.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that can be going on here, I have ran into both of these problems when running PCA from different libraries.

**FIRST**:
The columns and rows for opencv and tapkee are different. Opencv automatically creates the eigenvectors for their PCA samples in columns, every other library I have used for PCA places their eigenvectors in rows. This of course, changes your output. Tapkee may also be reading in  your data as rows instead of columns. 
Solution to this is to just output the eigenvectors of tapkee and opencv. Compare them, and see if the rows and columns are different. If they are, adjust as needs by either changing how your data is formatted for one of the PCAs, or output the eigenvectors and do the matrix multiplication yourself.

**SECOND**: tapkee may not be zero centering the matrix. opencv does this automatically, but you may have to do it manually for tapkee. Try zero centering it first (taking the average of each vector component and subtract from each data point).